# Mouse click needed in IE11 but not in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an `HTML` form that contains an `AJAX` call to get some data for the form, specifically a set of select options.  This works fine and in Firefox (50.0.2) the results are selectable after handling the `AJAX` success response. To prevent the form from submitting, before I hit enter on the data needed for the `AJAX jQuery GET`, I preventDefault on the form submission and all that works OK.

But in Internet Explorer 11 the select data are not immediately visible after processing the `AJAX` call response but if I mouse-click (left mouse button) anywhere in the form area, the `AJAX` response data becomes visible and selectable.

I have tried to use jQuery trigger click to simulate the left mouse click anywhere in the form area but I can't get that to work. Can anyone suggest how to get IE11 to behave like Firefox does?  Any suggestions will be most appreciated.

I have attached part of the `AJAX` response code if that might help - the response is in `XML` format..

```
// Now insert the received response(s) into the DOM:
$(data).find('result').each(function()
   {  
        // $(data).find('result') creates an array (which hopefully will not be empty)
        var dataToDisplay = $(this).text();
        // we now have a pipe-delimited string - convert it into an array
        var data_array = dataToDisplay.split('|');
        var dog_pk = data_array[0];
        var dog_name = data_array[1];
        var dog_breed = data_array[2];
        var customer = data_array[3];
        var the_rest = dog_name + ", " + dog_breed + ", " + customer;

        $('#dog_pk').append("<option value=" + dog_pk + ">" + the_rest + "</option>");
});
```

Here's the AJAX GET request:

```
$(function() 
    {   // get dog and owner names function
        $('#dogname_start').change(function(event)
            {   
                var params = "params=";
                params += String ($('#dogname_start').val());
                params = encodeURI(params);
                $('#add_appointment').submit(function(event)
                    {
                        event.preventDefault();
                        // alert("In dogname_start change form submit function, params are " + params);
                    });
                $.get(
                    './modules/get_dognames.xml.php',
                    params,
                    handle_response
                    );  // end AJAX get (note: type defaults to html)

            }); // end change function on #dogname_start        

    }); // end get dog and owner names function
```

Comment: Have you tried appending the values in memory first and only when complete attach it to the DOM. Updating the DOM each time in a loop can get very expensive.

Comment: I don't think I know how to do that - can you please help?  Also, the transaction volumes are very low. Do you mean create a JS variable with all the options and then append it?

Comment: Can you separate the AJAX request and the appending of the <option>s to debug this? When I use your code and manually specify a suitable `data` value, it works fine on IE11 for me.

Comment: I've included the AJAX request:

Comment: I've attached the AJAX request. The handle_response function just starts with 'function handle_response(data, status)' and the response data are just a series of pipe-delimited strings encased in XML <result></result> tags.

Comment: I've included the AJAX request. The params data sent with the AJAX get will be something like 'ab'.  The handle_response function starts with 'function handle_response(data, status) ...  the response data are just pipe-delimited strings encased in XML <result></result> tags.

Comment: I meant, what happens when you test your code without using AJAX? Just add a test button that sets data to a string, then calls `handle_response`. Does that work in IE11? We need to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, without AJAX it works fine, with AJAX it doesn't?  I also tested it in Chrome and Safari for Windows and they all work fine without the need to click the form area. It is only in IE11 that I need to click the form area and I can't seem to simulate that with jQuery trigger/click. If you have suggestions they would be most appreciated and thank you in anticipation.

Comment: FYI I set IE logging in the registry but no IE errors show.

Comment: OK, got it - use either 'bind' or 'on' in the dogname_start function - i.e., $('#dogname_start').on('change input', function(event)... or $('#dogname_start').bind('change input', function(event)... tested in IE11, FF, Chrome and Safari for Windows.

Comment: The above fires on every character entered - biding 'keydown' with a check for keycode 13 worked even better as it only sends the AJAX get when enter is hit.  Tested in FF, Chrome and Safari for Windows and IE11 OK.